# Setting up wordpress categories URLs

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress application. I have created a custom page for articles landing page. The permalink for articles is working fine but I have problems when I click on a category name. For example: If I click on "jobs" category the URL looks like http://www.mysite.com/category/articles/jobs/. I want it to look like http://www.mysite.com/jobs/.

I am not sure if this is something I did that is causing this or just default wordpress behaviour. So, any ideas/suggestion how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is either in this plugin or in its source code:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

It will work as long as you don't use the same slug for a page and a category (because they will in this case have the same permalink).